# How to find the indices of a certain value in pandas series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

Suppose I have a pandas series:

```
a = [1 ,2 ,4 ,2 ,7 , 2 ,8]
```

How to tell Python to return the indices that have values equals to 2?

Thanks.

Comment: That's not a pandas Series; but for pandas Series, try: `a.index[a.eq(2)].tolist()`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. Assumiming a is a pandas series.

```
f = a==2
indices = f[f].index
```